Combinatorial proof for probabilities of random real numbers in ascending runs
Considering an infinite sequence of real numbers chosen randomly within the interval $ [0,1] $, each value will be either higher or smaller then the previous one, and so we will get an infinite sequence of $ < $ and $ > $. Wlog we just consider the $ < $ and want to count the subsequences when they appear exactly $ n $ times in a row
As an example, consider
$ 0.42\ldots < 0.53\ldots > 0.28\ldots < 0.38\ldots < 0.45\ldots > 0.23\ldots < .78\ldots $
where we have a subsequence of length $ 1 (0.42\ldots < 0.53\ldots) $, a subsequence of length $ 2 (0.28\ldots < 0.38\ldots < 0.45\ldots) $ and so on.
We want to know the probability to find a subsequence of length $ n $. Here you can find an old question (not mine) about the same problem, with a simulation.
I solved the problem with a brute force method:
to compute the probability of length $ 1 $, I need a subsequence of $ 4 $ numbers $ (a, b, c, d) $, such that $ a > b < c > d $
$ \sum_{a=1} ^{n} \sum_{b=1} ^{a-1}\sum_{c=b+1} ^{n} \frac{(c-1)}{n^4} = \frac{(n - 1) (5 n^2 - 5 n + 2)}{24 n^3} $
So the probability is given by the limit $ P(1) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n - 1) (5 n^2 - 5 n + 2)}{24 n^3} = \frac{5}{24} $
Same way is possible to compute the probability of length $ 2 $, considering a subsequence of $ 5 $ numbers $ (a, b, c, d, e) $, such that $ a > b < c < d > e $
$ P(2) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{a=1} ^{n} \sum_{b=1} ^{a} \sum_{c=b+1} ^{n}\sum_{d=c+1} ^{n} \frac{(d-1)}{n^5} = \frac{11}{120} $
And so on.
But I would like a combinatorial proof of that, so for $ P(1) $ it's easy to recognize that the limiting value is just the number of alternating permutations of $ 4 $ elements, which are $ 5 $, on the total of $ 4! = 24 $ permutations.
I didn't understand how to prove the other cases: the numerators are the values of the A028387 sequence and I wonder if there is possible connection with the right-to-left minima of derangements, the concept is explained here and on page $ 22 $ you'll find a table with the same values of $ A028387 $. I know that alternating permutations and that subsequence of derangements are different concepts, but is there some kind of bijection or is it just a coincidence?
Is there any other way to prove combinatorially those probabilities?

Is the length supposed to be exactly $~n,~$ or at least $~n~?$

@user2661923 Exactly n

Cross-posted: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/475585/combinatorial-proof-for-probabilities-of-random-integers-in-ascending-runs

It looks like you want to calculate the probability of the event
$$
\{X_1>X_2\}\cap \{X_2<X_3<\dots<X_{n+2}\}\cap\{X_{n+2}>X_{n+3}\},
$$
where the $X_i$ are independent random variables each with $\text{Uniform}[0,1]$ distribution.
To help the notation, let's write $m=n+3$ so that we want the probability of
$$
\{X_1>X_2\}\cap \{X_2<X_3<\dots<X_{m-1}\}\cap\{X_{m-1}>X_{m}\}.
$$
Since the $X_i$ are independent and have continuous distributions, with probability $1$ they are all different. Since further they all have the same distribution, by symmetry all the $m!$ possible orderings (permutations) are equally likely.
So to calculate the probability, we can count how many permutations $\sigma=(\sigma_1, \dots, \sigma_m)\in S_m$ satisfy
$$
\sigma_1>\sigma_2, \,\,\,\,\sigma_2<\sigma_3<\dots<\sigma_{m-1}, \,\,\,\,\sigma_{m-1}>\sigma_{m}.
$$
There are $m(m-1)$ permutations which satisfy the middle condition (since as soon as we choose values for $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_m$, there is precisely one way to choose $(\sigma_2, \dots, \sigma_{m-1})$ to be in increasing order). So we just have to consider which pairs $(\sigma_1, \sigma_m)$ lead to the outer conditions holding. The cases we need to avoid are exactly those where
$(\sigma_1, \sigma_m)$ is $(1,a)$ for any $a$, or $(b,m)$ for any $b$, or is $(2,1)$ or $(m,m-1)$.
This yields a total of $2m-1$ of the $m(m-1)$ cases which need to be avoided. So overall, there are $m(m-1)-(2m-1)=m^2-3m+1$ permutations with the desired property.
So the event in question has probability $(m^2-3m+1)/m!$, which is $(n^2+3n+1)/(n+3)!$. This agrees with your values $5/24$ and $11/120$ in the cases $n=1$ and $n=2$.

Interestingly, your result does not use your assumption that the distribution is uniform. That is expected since, for any continuous distribution, we can transform it into a uniform distribution with the quantile transform. Since it is monotonous, that does not change the signs of the differences.

@JamesMartin Thank you for your answer! I tried to find a connection with right-to-left minima but it was simpler then I thought!
